# Unknown column in 'where clause' Rails 4

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

RoR noob here. I'm working on a RoR project with mysql.
I get this error when trying to delete a `foto`(photo) that has 1 or more `comentarios` (comments) in it.

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'fotos.foto_id' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM `comentarios` WHERE `comentarios`.`id` = 21

When destroying a photo, it looks for any comments that has the same `foto_id` so it can delete it as well. But the problem is that for some reason, it looks for `comentarios.id`  instead of `comentarios.foto_id`.

My `foto.rb` model has this line:

```
has_many :comentarios, dependent: :destroy
```

so it should delete any comments that any given photo has.

And my `comentario.rb` model has this:

```
belongs_to :foto
```

the `fotos#destroy` method in the controller looks like this:

```
def destroy
@foto.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to mias_path, notice: 'Foto eliminada correctamente.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end
```

end

As simple as it gets. But i can't manage to find the error.

The project is stored on github, so if you need to check any other piece of code, or want to try it out for yourself, it's there (it even includes the database i use): 
https://github.com/NashTG/PHOTOLOGG-2.0/
(the error happens when you log in as an admin, go to 'Todas las Fotos' and press 'Eliminar' on any of the photos that has any comments)

Thanks in advance (i really apreciate any fast answers because i'm on the deadline for this project)

Comment: The code looks good. Should have worked (unless you have some other code you didn't show, that interferes with this). Try restarting the server, just in case.

Comment: in that case, please tell me what code do you want me to show and i'll edit the  question

Comment: @NashTG can you please add the before_filter here

Comment: @NashTG: what is that `@foto`? where is it set?

Comment: @Deepak i don't really know what the before_filter is. is it in the controller? or where? .. sorry, i'm really new here

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `@foto` is set before in the fotos#new method. Its initialized as @foto = Foto.new

Comment: @NashTG: nah, that foto is not the one used here.

Comment: you will need to have something in @foto in this method as well if you are not using before_filter

Comment: @Deepak: it might be set via a `load_resource` or something

Comment: the only other mention that `@foto` has is on the  `create` method where it gets set as `@foto = current_user.fotos.new(foto_params)`

Answer (score 0):

> Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'fotos.foto_id' in 'where clause': DELETE FROM comentarios WHERE comentarios.id = 21

Look like you are calling foto_id on foto object.
But your associations say that foto_id is a field in `comentarios`

what is in `@foto`
check before_filter may be you are querying

```
@foto =  Foto.find(:id)
```

Comment: as far as i know, the `@foto`gets initialized in the `new` method in the same controller. And it sets it to `@foto = Foto.new`
Then it's mentioned in the `create` method where it's set to `@foto = current_user.fotos.new(foto_params)`

Comment: oh and i have now idea what the 'before_filter' is. Please enlighten me

Comment: @NashTG you also need to initialize `@foto` in destroy action

something like  `@foto = Foto.find(params[:id])`

Comment: i should have mentioned that when i try to delete a foto that has no comentarios in it, has no problems.

Comment: no, it's been that way since the beginning. It has no problems when deleting a _comentless_ foto, but gets that mysql2 error when deleting a foto with at least 1 comentario in it.